# Getting error "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms" at 'Import-Module "AzureAD" line in PS script

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, azure-powershell, azure-function-app

I am trying to deploy a simple powershell function app that contains the following commands:

```
Import-Module D:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1\AzureAD\AzureAD.psd1

Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $tenantId -Credential $Credential
```

AzureAD module files have already been copied from local repository "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureAD" to "D:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1\AzureAD" using KUDU.

Getting error at the Import-Module line, here is the ERROR stack trace:

```
ERROR: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.Exception             :Type       : System.IO.FileNotFoundExceptionMessage    : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.FileName   : System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089TargetSite :Name          : GetExportedTypesDeclaringType : System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798eMemberType    : MethodModule        : System.Private.CoreLib.dllStackTrace :at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes()at System.Reflection.Assembly.get_ExportedTypes()at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSnapInHelpers.GetAssemblyTypes(Assembly assembly, String name)at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSnapInHelpers.AnalyzeModuleAssemblyWithReflection(Assembly assembly, String name, PSSnapInInfo psSnapInInfo, PSModuleInfo moduleInfo, String helpFile, Dictionary`2& cmdlets, Dictionary`2& aliases, Dictionary`2& providers)at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSnapInHelpers.AnalyzePSSnapInAssembly(Assembly assembly, String name, PSSnapInInfo psSnapInInfo, PSModuleInfo moduleInfo, Dictionary`2& cmdlets, Dictionary`2& aliases, Dictionary`2& providers, String& helpFile)at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState.ImportCmdletsFromAssembly(Assembly assembly, PSModuleInfo module)at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadBinaryModule(PSModuleInfo parentModule, Boolean trySnapInName, String moduleName, String fileName, Assembly assemblyToLoad, String moduleBase, SessionState ss, ImportModuleOptions options, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, String prefix, Boolean loadTypes, Boolean loadFormats, Boolean& found, String shortModuleName, Boolean disableFormatUpdates)at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadBinaryModule(Boolean trySnapInName, String moduleName, String fileName, Assembly assemblyToLoad, String moduleBase, SessionState ss, ImportModuleOptions options, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, String prefix, Boolean loadTypes, Boolean loadFormats, Boolean& found)at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadModule(PSModuleInfo parentModule, String fileName, String moduleBase, String prefix, SessionState ss, Object privateData, ImportModuleOptions& options, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, Boolean& found, Boolean& moduleFileFound)at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadModuleNamedInManifest(PSModuleInfo parentModule, ModuleSpecification moduleSpecification, String moduleBase, Boolean searchModulePath, String prefix, SessionState ss, ImportModuleOptions options, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, Boolean loadTypesFiles, Boolean loadFormatFiles, Object privateData, Boolean& found, String shortModuleName, Nullable`1 manifestLanguageMode)at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadModuleManifest(String moduleManifestPath, ExternalScriptInfo manifestScriptInfo, Hashtable data, Hashtable localizedData, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, Version minimumVersion, Version maximumVersion, Version requiredVersion, Nullable`1 requiredModuleGuid, ImportModuleOptions& options, Boolean& containedErrors)at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadModuleManifest(ExternalScriptInfo scriptInfo, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, Version minimumVersion, Version maximumVersion, Version requiredVersion, Nullable`1 requiredModuleGuid, ImportModuleOptions& options)at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadModule(PSModuleInfo parentModule, String fileName, String moduleBase, String prefix, SessionState ss, Object privateData, ImportModuleOptions& options, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, Boolean& found, Boolean& moduleFileFound)at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadModule(String fileName, String moduleBase, String prefix, SessionState ss, ImportModuleOptions& options, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, Boolean& found)at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand.ImportModule_LocallyViaName(ImportModuleOptions importModuleOptions, String name)at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand.ImportModule_LocallyViaName_WithTelemetry(ImportModuleOptions importModuleOptions, String name)at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand.ProcessRecord()at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()Source     : System.Private.CoreLibHResult    : -2147024894CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundExceptionFullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommandInvocationInfo        :MyCommand        : Import-ModuleScriptLineNumber : 22OffsetInLine     : 5HistoryId        : 1ScriptName       : D:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1\run.ps1Line             : Import-Module D:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1\AzureAD\AzureAD.psd1PositionMessage  : At D:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1\run.ps1:22 char:5+     Import-Module D:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1\AzureAD\AzureAD.p …+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~PSScriptRoot     : D:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1PSCommandPath    : D:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1\run.ps1InvocationName   : Import-ModuleCommandOrigin    : InternalScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, D:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1\run.ps1: line 22at <ScriptBlock>, D:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1\run.ps1: line 31Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.Rpc.RpcException : Result: ERROR: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.Exception             :Type       : System.IO.FileNotFoundExceptionMessage    : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.FileName   : System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089TargetSite :Name          : GetExportedTypesDeclaringType : System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798eMemberType    : MethodModule        : System.Private.CoreLib.dllStackTrace :at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes()at System.Reflection.Assembly.get_ExportedTypes()at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSnapInHelpers.GetAssemblyTypes(Assembly assembly, String name)at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSnapInHelpers.AnalyzeModuleAssemblyWithReflection(Assembly assembly, String name, PSSnapInInfo psSnapInInfo, PSModuleInfo moduleInfo, String helpFile, Dictionary`2& cmdlets, Dictionary`2& aliases, Dictionary`2& providers)at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSnapInHelpers.AnalyzePSSnapInAssembly(Assembly assembly, String name, PSSnapInInfo psSnapInInfo, PSModuleInfo moduleInfo, Dictionary`2& cmdlets, Dictionary`2& aliases, Dictionary`2& providers, String& helpFile)at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState.ImportCmdletsFromAssembly(Assembly assembly, PSModuleInfo module)at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadBinaryModule(PSModuleInfo parentModule, Boolean trySnapInName, String moduleName, String fileName, Assembly assemblyToLoad, String moduleBase, SessionState ss, ImportModuleOptions options, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, String prefix, Boolean loadTypes, Boolean loadFormats, Boolean& found, String shortModuleName, Boolean disableFormatUpdates)at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadBinaryModule(Boolean trySnapInName, String moduleName, String fileName, Assembly assemblyToLoad, String moduleBase, SessionState ss, ImportModuleOptions options, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, String prefix, Boolean loadTypes, Boolean loadFormats, Boolean& found)at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadModule(PSModuleInfo parentModule, String fileName, String moduleBase, String prefix, SessionState ss, Object privateData, ImportModuleOptions& options, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, Boolean& found, Boolean& moduleFileFound)at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadModuleNamedInManifest(PSModuleInfo parentModule, ModuleSpecification moduleSpecification, String moduleBase, Boolean searchModulePath, String prefix, SessionState ss, ImportModuleOptions options, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, Boolean loadTypesFiles, Boolean loadFormatFiles, Object privateData, Boolean& found, String shortModuleName, Nullable`1 manifestLanguageMode)at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadModuleManifest(String moduleManifestPath, ExternalScriptInfo manifestScriptInfo, Hashtable data, Hashtable localizedData, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, Version minimumVersion, Version maximumVersion, Version requiredVersion, Nullable`1 requiredModuleGuid, ImportModuleOptions& options, Boolean& containedErrors)at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadModuleManifest(ExternalScriptInfo scriptInfo, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, Version minimumVersion, Version maximumVersion, Version requiredVersion, Nullable`1 requiredModuleGuid, ImportModuleOptions& options)at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadModule(PSModuleInfo parentModule, String fileName, String moduleBase, String prefix, SessionState ss, Object privateData, ImportModuleOptions& options, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, Boolean& found, Boolean& moduleFileFound)at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadModule(String fileName, String moduleBase, String prefix, SessionState ss, ImportModuleOptions& options, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, Boolean& found)at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand.ImportModule_LocallyViaName(ImportModuleOptions importModuleOptions, String name)at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand.ImportModule_LocallyViaName_WithTelemetry(ImportModuleOptions importModuleOptions, String name)at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand.ProcessRecord()at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()Source     : System.Private.CoreLibHResult    : -2147024894CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundExceptionFullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommandInvocationInfo        :MyCommand        : Import-ModuleScriptLineNumber : 22OffsetInLine     : 5HistoryId        : 1ScriptName       : D:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1\run.ps1Line             : Import-Module D:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1\AzureAD\AzureAD.psd1PositionMessage  : At D:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1\run.ps1:22 char:5+     Import-Module D:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1\AzureAD\AzureAD.p …+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~PSScriptRoot     : D:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1PSCommandPath    : D:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1\run.ps1InvocationName   : Import-ModuleCommandOrigin    : InternalScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, D:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1\run.ps1: line 22at <ScriptBlock>, D:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1\run.ps1: line 31Exception: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.Stack: 
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes()at System.Reflection.Assembly.get_ExportedTypes()at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSnapInHelpers.GetAssemblyTypes(Assembly assembly, String name)at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSnapInHelpers.AnalyzeModuleAssemblyWithReflection(Assembly assembly, String name, PSSnapInInfo psSnapInInfo, PSModuleInfo moduleInfo, String helpFile, Dictionary`2& cmdlets, Dictionary`2& aliases, Dictionary`2& providers)at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSnapInHelpers.AnalyzePSSnapInAssembly(Assembly assembly, String name, PSSnapInInfo psSnapInInfo, PSModuleInfo moduleInfo, Dictionary`2& cmdlets, Dictionary`2& aliases, Dictionary`2& providers, String& helpFile)at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState.ImportCmdletsFromAssembly(Assembly assembly, PSModuleInfo module)at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadBinaryModule(PSModuleInfo parentModule, Boolean trySnapInName, String moduleName, String fileName, Assembly assemblyToLoad, String moduleBase, SessionState ss, ImportModuleOptions options, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, String prefix, Boolean loadTypes, Boolean loadFormats, Boolean& found, String shortModuleName, Boolean disableFormatUpdates)at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadBinaryModule(Boolean trySnapInName, String moduleName, String fileName, Assembly assemblyToLoad, String moduleBase, SessionState ss, ImportModuleOptions options, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, String prefix, Boolean loadTypes, Boolean loadFormats, Boolean& found)at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadModule(PSModuleInfo parentModule, String fileName, String moduleBase, String prefix, SessionState ss, Object privateData, ImportModuleOptions& options, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, Boolean& found, Boolean& moduleFileFound)at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadModuleNamedInManifest(PSModuleInfo parentModule, ModuleSpecification moduleSpecification, String moduleBase, Boolean searchModulePath, String prefix, SessionState ss, ImportModuleOptions options, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, Boolean loadTypesFiles, Boolean loadFormatFiles, Object privateData, Boolean& found, String shortModuleName, Nullable`1 manifestLanguageMode)at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadModuleManifest(String moduleManifestPath, ExternalScriptInfo manifestScriptInfo, Hashtable data, Hashtable localizedData, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, Version minimumVersion, Version maximumVersion, Version requiredVersion, Nullable`1 requiredModuleGuid, ImportModuleOptions& options, Boolean& containedErrors)at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadModuleManifest(ExternalScriptInfo scriptInfo, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, Version minimumVersion, Version maximumVersion, Version requiredVersion, Nullable`1 requiredModuleGuid, ImportModuleOptions& options)at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadModule(PSModuleInfo parentModule, String fileName, String moduleBase, String prefix, SessionState ss, Object privateData, ImportModuleOptions& options, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, Boolean& found, Boolean& moduleFileFound)at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadModule(String fileName, String moduleBase, String prefix, SessionState ss, ImportModuleOptions& options, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, Boolean& found)at
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In PowerShell 7, the AzureAD module needs to be explicitly imported with the -UseWindowsPowershell switch, so that it is loaded into a separate Windows PowerShell session:

```
Import-Module AzureAD -UseWindowsPowerShell
```

For more details and caveats, see https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-powershell-worker/issues/544#issuecomment-702324803

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked. Now I am able to Connect to AzureAD.

Answer (score 0):

I still get the same issue in the terminal of my Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS with Visual Studio Code 1.53.2 and PSVersion 7.1.1

PS /media/xxx> Import-Module AzureAD -UseWindowsPowerShell

PS /media/xxx> Import-Module -name AzureAD

Import-Module: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.